# Unable to save due to Unpermitted parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi in Rails App I have a form generated in the Scaffold way where the user inputs Arrival and Departure fields among other fields. Rails automatically generated drop downs for year , Month , day of month , hour , minutes and the other fields for editing , viewing etc but when trying to update the Arrival and the Departure fields its failing.The database is not updated with Arrival and Departure timestamps while the other fields are updated normally.

Any ideas of how to insert the date fields in the database correctly ?

This is my database table:

```
class CreateLineItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :line_items do |t|
      t.belongs_to :venue, index: true
      t.belongs_to :route, index: true
      t.text :comment
      t.integer :rating
      t.string :price
      t.integer :order
      t.timestamp :arrival
      t.timestamp :departure

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This is from the Controller:

```
def permitted_params
params.permit(:line_item => [:comment, :rating ,:price,:order ,
{:arrival=>   [],:departure=>[]} ,:id])          
end
```

This is from the Log:

```
Processing by LineItemsController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",

 "authenticity_token"=>"beEbBrCOPKwx7U6pJbJEi9V8Mojt8Zkltco82f1gEZU=", "line_item"=>`{"route_id"=>"1", "comment"=>"test 123", "rating"=>"2", "price"=>"10 `euros", "order"=>"9", "arrival(1i)"=>"2010", "arrival(2i)"=>"7", "arrival(3i)"=>"15", `"arrival(4i)"=>"11", "arrival(5i)"=>"13", "departure(1i)"=>"", "departure(2i)"=>"", "departure(3i)"=>"", "departure(4i)"=>"", "departure(5i)"=>""}, "commit"=>"Update Line `item", "id"=>"21"}

Unpermitted parameters: route_id, arrival(1i), arrival(2i), arrival(3i), arrival(4i), arrival(5i), departure(1i), departure(2i), departure(3i), departure(4i), departure(5i)
Unpermitted parameters: utf8, _method, authenticity_token, commit, id
(3.1ms)  BEGIN
SQL (10.8ms)  UPDATE "line_items" SET "order" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "line_items"."id" = 21  [["order", 9], ["updated_at", Wed, 09 Apr 2014 10:56:06 UTC +00:00]]
```

EDIT:

This is the new Log after the change suggested, none of the values is now stored in the table :

```
Started PATCH "/line_items/21" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-09 14:34:07 +0300
Processing by LineItemsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"beEbBrCOPKwx7U6pJbJEi9V8Mojt8Zkltco82f1gEZU=", "line_item"=>{"route_id"=>"1", "comment"=>"test 123", "rating"=>"7", "price"=>"20 euros", "order"=>"1", "arrival(1i)"=>"2012", "arrival(2i)"=>"8", "arrival(3i)"=>"15", "arrival(4i)"=>"13", "arrival(5i)"=>"14", "departure(1i)"=>"2012", "departure(2i)"=>"5", "departure(3i)"=>"15", "departure(4i)"=>"11", "departure(5i)"=>"14"}, "commit"=>"Update Line item", "id"=>"21"}
  LineItem Load (4.5ms)  SELECT "line_items".* FROM "line_items" WHERE "line_items"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "21"]]
Unpermitted parameters: route_id
   (4.6ms)  BEGIN
   (3.9ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/line_items/21
Completed 302 Found in 31ms (ActiveRecord: 13.1ms)
```

Comment: Thanks ! The "upermitted parameters" is now gone from the log .. but now none of the fields of the form get updated.

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
params.require(:line_item).permit(:comment, :rating, :price, :order, :arrival, :departure, :id)
```

Comment: I used the code above , none of the database fields gets updated now. The "unpermitted parameters" from the log has disappeared. The log has no sql update statement.

Comment: @user3172824 I cannot say what's wrong using data you provided . Plus it's other problem than the one from the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, it was because I had `url:` instead of `model:` in `form_with`

Wrong:

```
<%= form_with(url: @message, method: :post) do |f| %> 

<%= f.label :body %> 
<%= f.text_area :body %> 
<%= f.hidden_field user_id: current_user.id %>
<%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Right:

```
<%= form_with(model: @message, method: :post) do |f| %> 

<%= f.label :body %> 
<%= f.text_area :body %> 
<%= f.hidden_field user_id: current_user.id %>
<%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```